# Server side event confusion with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, olympus-camerakit

I am attempting to create a web page that will allow a user to capture images from a camera attached to the server using ASP.NET. The camera is an olympus and the server side code has access to all of the synchronous calls that are in the sdk of the camera.
The problem arises when I attempt to capture an image.
The way it works in the SDK is that you first tell the camera to take the image, then add a listener to an event that is trigger by the camera to then begin downloading the image from the camera once it is finished capturing the image.
The event is never triggered so I am currently unable to download the image from the camera.
The code that binds the listener to a function and tells the camera to take the picture, is inside a button's server side code.
Essentially I am wondering how one could have an event listener for something that changes on the server, like the state of the camera that is attached.

Comment: Are you binding the event handler on postback?  If not, the event won't fire to your handler.

Comment: That might be the issue, I am actually binding the event on page load rather than on postback, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect you to have problems with this. For instance, I bet the camera assumes it is in use by a single desktop application at a time. Calling it from a web application is quite different, as each request could be from a different user, and could be unrelated to what's already going on with the camera.

I recommend you communicate with the camera through a Windows Service. The service would communicate with the web application through a WCF Service hosted in the Windows Service. It would tell the camera to take the image, and would attach to the event. When the event fires, it would download the image from the camera and return it to the caller of the web service.

The WCF service would probably have to ensure that only one user is using the camera at a time. If the camera is already in use, it would have to reject the call.

Answer (score 0):

Server side event captures can get a bit tricky.  It has been a while since I've done this so I'm writing completely from my foggy memory ...

Attaching to a server side event from a page class introduces a problem with the life cycle of the class.  Once the page is delivered, the instance of the class is no longer in scope so whatever event handler you assigned to the camera is no longer in scope either.  We used two different mechanisms for dealing with this.

A) Assign a static method to the event handler.  A static method isn't tied to an specific instance of a class and will persist even after the instance of the page is no longer in scope.

B) Assign a method in the GLOBAL class to capture the event on the Application(or session)_Start event.  This keeps the event handler outside the scope of the page class as well.

In either of these instances your event handlers will need to set some flag that can be read globally to indicate the image is ready and your page will need to poll a page (or handler) or refresh to find out of the image is ready.

You will also need to look at the scope of the camera's API class instantiation. If the class is instantiated as a member of the page's class, it drops off the face of the earth as soon as the page is finished doing it's thing and the event will not get raised.  The camera class will need to be either static, global or spawned off to another independent thread.

Hope my foggy ramplings help.  Good luck.